Error code 64 when running "npm run sass" in Blazor
I am doing a Blazor Application in Visual Studio 2022 and Net 8.. I have installed Node v20.18.0 and npm version 10.8.2
I added those lines in .csproj
<Target Name="CompileScopedScss" BeforeTargets="Compile">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ScopedScssFiles Include="Features/**/*.razor.scss" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Exec Command="npm run sass –– %(ScopedScssFiles.Identity) %(relativedir)%(filename).css" />
</Target>

I convert all sass pages in css. But I have a compile error
The command npm run sass -- Features/pages....... exited with code 64...

If I remove line
<Exec Command="npm run sass –– %(ScopedScssFiles.Identity) %(relativedir)%(filename).css" />

the application compile...
I took this line from an Old Blazor tutorial...
How can I replace this line and solve the problem?
Thanks
